# Triggers in sql: Mutating Trigger issue

Tags: oracle, triggers

I want to insert rows into another table called excercise_scores when a row is inserted in attempts table. There are multiple tries for an excercise and based on the scoring method(which can be latest score, average of all attempts or maximum score from all attempts), I have to insert score in the excercise_scores table.
So when Inserting scores into excercise_score, I also have to check what is the grading method for the excercise, get the score from attempts table based on the method and then finally insert into excercise_scores table.

For that I have created a SQL trigger as follows

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER scores_trigger AFTER
 INSERT
  ON attempts FOR EACH row DECLARE P1 VARCHAR2(50);
 SCORES FLOAT;
 v_exists VARCHAR2(1) := 'F';
 BEGIN
  BEGIN
   SELECT
    'T'
     INTO
     v_exists
   FROM
     excercise_scores
   WHERE
    user_id        = :NEW.USER_ID
    AND EXCERCISE_ID = :NEW.EXCERCISE_ID
    AND COURSE_ID    = :NEW.COURSE_ID;
   EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
    NULL;
  END;
 SELECT
  SELECTION_METHOD
 INTO
  P1
 FROM
  EXCERCISES
 WHERE
  EXCERCISE_ID = :NEW.EXCERCISE_ID
 AND COURSE_ID  = :NEW.COURSE_ID;
 IF (P1         = 'Latest') THEN
   SCORES      := :NEW.TOTAL_POINTS;
 ELSE
   IF (P1 = 'best') THEN
     SELECT
       MAX(TOTAL_POINTS)
     INTO
       SCORES
     FROM
      ATTEMPTS
     WHERE
      EXCERCISE_ID = :NEW.EXCERCISE_ID
     AND COURSE_ID  = :NEW.COURSE_ID
     AND USER_ID    = :NEW.USER_ID;         
   ELSE
     SELECT
       AVG(TOTAL_POINTS)
     INTO
       SCORES
     FROM
       ATTEMPTS
     WHERE
       EXCERCISE_ID = :NEW.EXCERCISE_ID
     AND COURSE_ID  = :NEW.COURSE_ID
     AND USER_ID    = :NEW.USER_ID;
   END IF;
 END IF;
 IF v_exists = 'T' THEN
   UPDATE
     EXCERCISE_SCORES
   SET
     TOTAL_POINTS = SCORES
   WHERE
     user_id        = :NEW.USER_ID
   AND EXCERCISE_ID = :NEW.EXCERCISE_ID
   AND COURSE_ID    = :NEW.COURSE_ID;
 ELSE
   INSERT
   INTO
     EXCERCISE_SCORES VALUES
     (
       :NEW.EXCERCISE_ID,
       :NEW.COURSE_ID,
       :NEW.COURSE_ID,
       SCORES
      ) ;
 END IF;
END;
```

But when I try to execute this trigger, it gives me the following error:

```
Error starting at line 47 in command:
insert into attempts values(21,0,'vshesha',3,'CSC540',TO_DATE('20141014', 'YYYYMMDD'),12,6)
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-04091: table VSHESHA.ATTEMPTS is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "VSHESHA.SCORES_TRIGGER", line 18
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'VSHESHA.SCORES_TRIGGER'
04091. 00000 -  "table %s.%s is mutating, trigger/function may not see it"
*Cause:    A trigger (or a user defined plsql function that is referenced in
       this statement) attempted to look at (or modify) a table that was
       in the middle of being modified by the statement which fired it.
*Action:   Rewrite the trigger (or function) so it does not read that table.
```

I couldn't figure out why it is giving this error as I am running the trigger after insert. Generally mutating table issue should not come in after insert triggers.

Can anyone please help me with this. I am suck with this for a long time now.

Comment: `SQL Error: ORA-04091` ? please adapt your Tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oralce you can use [COMPOUND TRIGGER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#LNPLS2005). In your case it would be similar to this one. I did not copy all your operations to this example, but you should get the principle.

However, as the other replies already mentionied. The preferred way should be to move all this logic into a PL/SQL procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER scores_trigger
    FOR INSERT ON attempts
    COMPOUND TRIGGER

    TYPE RowTableType IS TABLE OF ROWID;
    RowTable RowTableType;
    aRow attempts%ROWTYPE;

    SCORES FLOAT;
    v_exists VARCHAR2(1) := 'F';

    BEFORE STATEMENT IS
    BEGIN
        RowTable := RowTableType();
    END BEFORE STATEMENT;

    AFTER EACH ROW IS
    BEGIN
        RowTable.EXTEND;
        RowTable(RowTable.LAST) := :NEW.ROWID;
    END AFTER EACH ROW;

    AFTER STATEMENT IS
    BEGIN

        FOR i IN RowTable.FIRST..RowTable.LAST LOOP
            SELECT * 
            INTO aRow
            FROM attempts
            WHERE ROWID = RowTable(i);

            SELECT SELECTION_METHOD
            INTO P1
            FROM EXCERCISES
            WHERE EXCERCISE_ID = aRow.EXCERCISE_ID
                AND COURSE_ID  = aRow.COURSE_ID;

            IF P1 = 'Latest' THEN
                SCORES := :NEW.TOTAL_POINTS;
            ELSE
                IF (P1 = 'best') THEN
                    SELECT MAX(TOTAL_POINTS)
                    INTO SCORES
                    FROM ATTEMPTS
                    WHERE EXCERCISE_ID = aRow.EXCERCISE_ID
                        AND COURSE_ID  = aRow.COURSE_ID
                        AND USER_ID    = aRow.USER_ID;         
                ELSE
                    SELECT AVG(TOTAL_POINTS)
                    INTO SCORES
                    FROM ATTEMPTS
                    WHERE EXCERCISE_ID = aRow.EXCERCISE_ID
                        AND COURSE_ID  = aRow.COURSE_ID
                        AND USER_ID    = aRow.USER_ID;
                END IF;
            END IF;

        END LOOP;

    END AFTER STATEMENT;
END scores_trigger;
```

An example for an PL/SQL procedure would be this one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_score(V_EXCERCISE IN SCORES.EXCERCISE_ID%TYPE, V_COURSE IN SCORES.COURSE_ID%TYPE, V_USER IN USER_ID%TYPE) IS

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO insert_score (EXCERCISE_ID, COURSE_ID, USER_ID) VALUES (V_EXCERCISE, V_COURSE, V_USER);

    BEGIN
    SELECT 'T'
    INTO v_exists
    FROM excercise_scores
    WHERE user_id        = :NEW.USER_ID
        AND EXCERCISE_ID = :NEW.EXCERCISE_ID
        AND COURSE_ID    = :NEW.COURSE_ID;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            RETURN;
    END;

    ... other stuff

END insert_score;
```

For the insert you have to call this procedure instead of doing the insert directly.

Comment: Thank you so much! I wrote the trigger on similar lines again.

Comment: @Kristy, don't say "thank you", accept the answer and upvote it.

Comment: Upvote requires reputation of 15 which I don't have as of now :(

Answer (score 2):

The error message is pretty self-explaining, and the SQL statement that's causing it is:

```
     SELECT
       AVG(TOTAL_POINTS)
     INTO
       SCORES
     FROM
       ATTEMPTS
     WHERE
       EXCERCISE_ID = :NEW.EXCERCISE_ID
     AND COURSE_ID  = :NEW.COURSE_ID
     AND USER_ID    = :NEW.USER_ID;
```

You're selecting from `ATTEMPTS`, and that's the table that's currently changing. There's no simple solution for it - the most sensible approach is to use move your business logic out of the trigger and into your application code (see [AskTom about mutating table errors](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9579487119866) ).

BTW: Your statement that "Generally mutating table issue should not come in after insert triggers." is plain wrong. See [database journal article](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/article.php/3329121/The-Mutation-error-in-Oracle-Database-Triggers.htm) for a longer explanation (in short: you will *always* run into mutating table errors with multi-row inserts, and in *almost every case* run into errors with single-row inserts).

Comment: I am new to triggers and i couldn't figure out how else can I do this. Where should I move the logic and how?

Comment: I assume you have some kind of application that uses your database. Presumably, this application is written in a programming language different from SQL. Either use that programming language to update your data after the insert action, or put your logic into a PL/SQL stored procedure that first performs the insert and then performs the secondary inserts/updates.